# Proving that a quotient of hypergeometric functions is smaller than a certain function

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, hypergeometric-functions

Im trying to prove that $\forall w \in (0,1), \forall k \in \left(0,\frac{1}{5}\right)$:
$$h_k(w) = \left[\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1-w}{1+w} \right) }{_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1-w}{1+w} \right) } \cdot \frac{1}{1+w}\left(\frac{k}{k-1} + w(1-w) \right)\right] -1 <0 $$

Numerically I can see that the function between square brackets actually fulfills that $\forall w \in (0,1), \forall k \in \left(0,\frac{1}{5}\right)$:

$$ h_k(w)+1 < \frac{1-w}{2} < \frac{1}{2}$$

Of course if you can prove the second identity you obviously have the first (and room to spare). I have been able to prove the following:

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow 0} (h_k(w)+1) = \frac{1-w}{2}$$
But haven't been able to prove that $h_k(w)$ is decreasing in $k$ or anything that might help me. In case you might need it, the way I proved the limit was using the sum definition of the hypergeometric function, taylor expandind around $k=0$ the quotient of Gamma functions to order $k\sqrt{k}$ , and then doing the sums (which are exact), taylor expanding the denominator around $k=0$ again, and multiplying, which grants me (in this analysis I substituted $\frac{1-w}{1+w}$ by $z$):

$$\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k};z\right) }{_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k};z\right) } \sim \frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{kz}{2(1-z)^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(k^2\right) \rightarrow \frac{1}{1-z} \mapsto \frac{1+w}{2w}$$

Which implies 
$$h_0(w) +1 = \frac{1-w}{2}$$